# jmeter | Get pass/fail count of samples from jtl file

Tags: ant, jmeter

I am using jmeter for functional testing and have 2 different jmx.
The first jmx has all APIs automated and the second jmx is used to send the html report (generated using Ant-Jmeter task) through SMTP sampler.

Now, I want to send the count of Total, Pass, Fail sample counts in the same email by parsing the jtl file generated by first jmx.

Here is what I can see in the jtl file, s="true" and s="false".
I want count of the same and save it as property to use it further in SMTP sampler.
Example in jtl:

```
<sample t="2" it="0" lt="2" ct="0" ts="1565592433268" s="false" lb="Verify Latest Patch" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Tenant_Login 3-1" dt="text" by="9" sby="0" ng="1" na="1">
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```

   it will instruct JMeter to immediately write results to file as soon as they're available
2. Add [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
3. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to the TearDown Thread Group
4. Configure it as follows:

   - Protocol: `file`
   - Path: `location of your .jtl result file

     [image]
5. Add [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0/) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
6. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `successCount`
   - XPath query: `count(//sample[@s='true'])`

     [image]
7. That's it, now you should be able to refer the successful samples count as `${successCount}` where required

Comment: The XPath extractor worked perfectly for me. Thanks for the help!